# Why can't I use the diamond operator with an array in Perl?

Tags: perl, file, diamond-operator

> **Code**

```
$ cat test1
hello 
i am 
lazer

nananana
$ cat 1.pl
use strict;
use warnings;

my @fh;
open $fh[0], '<', 'test1', or die $!;

my @res1 = <$fh[0]>;  # Way1: why does this not work as expected?
print @res1."\n"; 

my $fh2 = $fh[0];
my @res2 = <$fh2>;    # Way2: this works!
print @res2."\n";
```

> **Run**

```
$ perl 1.pl
1
5
$
```

I am not sure why `Way1` does not work as expected while `Way2` does. Aren't those two methods the same? What is happening here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Because of the dual nature of the <> operator (i.e. is it [glob](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob.html) or [readline](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/readline.html)?), the rules are that to behave as readline, you can only have a bareword or a simple scalar inside the brackets. So you'll have to either assign the array element to a simple scalar (as in your example), or use the readline function directly.

Comment: `perl -le 'print for < < <=> > >'`

Comment: @tchrist: Any point to that other than being a fun example of glob?

Answer (score 14):

Because from [perlop](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/perlop):

> If what's within the angle brackets is neither a filehandle nor a simple scalar variable containing a filehandle name, typeglob, or typeglob reference, it is interpreted as a filename pattern to be globbed, and either a list of filenames or the next filename in the list is returned, depending on context. This distinction is determined on syntactic grounds alone. That means `<$x>` is always a readline() from an indirect handle, but `<$hash{key}>` is always a glob().

You can spell the `<>` operator as [readline](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/perlfunc#readline) instead to avoid problems with this magic.

Answer (score 8):

Anything more complex than a bareword (interpreted as a file handle) or a simple scalar `$var` is interpreted as an argument to the `glob()` function.  Only barewords and simple scalars are treated as file handles to be iterated by the `<...>` operator.

Basically the rules are:

```
<bareword> ~~  readline bareword
<$scalar>  ~~  readline $scalar
<$array[0]> ~~ glob "$array[0]"
<anything else> ~~ glob ...
```

Answer (score 6):

It's because `<$fh[0]>` is parsed as `glob($fh[0])`.

Use `readline` instead:

```
my @res1 = readline($fh[0]);
```